# audio is not playing on button click

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

I want to play a audio on `Button` click. I have tried this code but audio is not playing:-

```
NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sound" ofType:@"mp3"];
NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];
AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer  = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:soundFileURL error:nil];
audioPlayer.delegate = self;
audioPlayer.volume=1.0;
[audioPlayer setNumberOfLoops:1];
[audioPlayer play];
```

Comment: what the output you get here `soundFileURL`

Comment: pls create property of AVAudioPlayer or declare as instance variable so that AVAudioPlayer object can have scope outside of that method.

Comment: who keeps the `AVAudioPlayer` instance alive when your scope runs out?

Answer (score 1):

First, it appears you are using `initWithData` to access an audio file pointed to by a URL.

You should instead use `initWithContentsOfU‌RL`.

---

Another issue could be due to a common error in implementing the audio player.

If the `AVAudioPlayer` you are creating is inside a function, it will be released, or deallocated, at the end of the function. This is why the audio does not play.

To fix this problem, make the `AVAudioPlayer` a property or instance variable in your class so that it does not get immediately deallocated.

For example, a property is declared in your header as

```
@property(strong, nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
```

and initialized in your implementation with

```
self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:soundFileURL error:nil];
```

---

If this does not solve your problem, then the issue is likely to do with the file pointed to by your URL.

Comment: This should be the solution.

Answer (score 1):

you haven't created a player item

//declare in .h file

```
AVPlayerItem *playerItem;
```

//then in .m file

```
player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
```

after that play it

```
   [player play];
```

Comment: Pardon my observation, the question is about an `AVAudioPlayer` and not an `AVPlayer`.

Comment: yes the question is about audio player , but i needs playeritem to play...

Comment: I know what you are talking about and it is not a requirement to explicitly create the playerItem. A player item is implicitly created if an AVPlayer is inited with a URL. From the docs on initWithURL, "This method implicitly creates an AVPlayerItem object. You can get the player item using currentItem."

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *soundFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/test.mp3", 
   [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]];
NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];

AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL  error:nil];
player.numberOfLoops = -1; //Infinite

[player play];
```

Answer (score 0):

print   "soundFileURL" . check whether it is null(in case **soundFileURL** contains spaces it results/prints null ) and if it not a null value check the file name is spelled exactly correct or not(i.e., here your file name is "***sound***")

Answer (score 0):

```
var asyncaAudioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!

let audioFilePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(fileName, ofType: "mp3")

let audioFileUrl = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(audioFilePath!)

asyncaAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: audioFileUrl, fileTypeHint: nil)

audioPlayerArray.append(asyncaAudioPlayer)

asyncaAudioPlayer.prepareToPlay()


asyncaAudioPlayer.play()
```

Comment: Check you are getting file path or not.
Type should be which ever you want
replace file name with your own.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you set NSURL for initWithData -> Wrong. 
in case it sound play multi time, you should prepare your sound Data and keep it as strong ref.

and  you should use CGD and global queue instead of main queue.

```
-(void)onTouchUpInside{
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0),   ^{
        AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer  = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:self.soundFileData error:nil];
        audioPlayer.delegate = self;
        audioPlayer.volume=1.0;
        [audioPlayer setNumberOfLoops:1];
        if ([audioPlayer prepareToPlay] && [audioPlayer play])
        {
            NSLog(@"play Success!");
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Failed to play the audio file.");
        }

    });
}
```